# line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls? - Edit

Tags: r

In the book *A first course in statistical programming* with R by W. John Braun and Duncan J. Murdoch page 31 (Data frames and `read.table` function), they explain

> Data sets frequently consist of more than one column of data, where
>   each column represents measurements of a single variable. Each row
>   usually represents a single observation. This format is referred to as
>   *case-by-variable* format.
>
> For example, the following data set consists of four observations on
>   the three variables x, y, and z :

```
x y z
61 13 4
175 21 18
111 24 14
124 23 18
```

> If such a data set is stored in a file called `pretend.dat` in the
>   directory myfiles on the C:drive (*this is in Windows, but I use a
>   Mac*), then it can be read into an R data frame. This can be the commands 
>   accomplished by typing `pretend.df <-
>   read.table("c:/myfiles/pretend.dat", header = T)`.
>
> In a data frame, the columns are named. To see the x colum, type
>   `pretend.df$x`

**Problem (book) :** Display the row 1, column 3 element of `pretend.df`.

So far I created with my Macbook Pro this file with Excel (.xlsx or csv??). From there, I wrote `pretend.df <- read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.xlsx", header = T)`, and an error occured

```
    Warning messages:
1: In read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.xlsx", header = T) :
  line 1 appears to contain embedded nulls
2: In read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.xlsx", header = T) :
  line 3 appears to contain embedded nulls
3: In read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.xlsx", header = T) :
  line 4 appears to contain embedded nulls
4: In read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.xlsx", header = T) :
  line 5 appears to contain embedded nulls
5: In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

If I try the command `pretend.df <- read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.csv", header = T)`, I got

```
Warning message:
In read.table("/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.csv", header = T) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/Users/jg24/Documents/R/Classeur1.csv'
```

**Question :** Could anyone be able to tell me what's wrong with my last command, and how could I modify it?

**P.S.** I'm a new user of RStudio. Could anyone be able to show me this problem with this software?

Comment: maybe this can help? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872946/read-csv-throws-error)

Comment: @simone This exercise wants I use the read.table() function. With the current link, I don't understand, but it still doesn't work. Could you explain a full solution?

Comment: did you save the file as a csv? you can do that with excel

Comment: Yes, but if I use the command `pretend.df1 <- read.table(file.choose(), header = T, sep = "\t") on the file `pretend.dat.csv` or `Classeur1.csv` here, I got `Warning message:
In read.table(file.choose(), header = T, sep = "\t") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on '/Users/jg24/Documents/R/pretend.dat.csv'` ? I just don't know what happen

Comment: I see. Have you tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990654/incomplete-final-line-warning-when-trying-to-read-a-csv-file-into-r)? (answer by @NicolasStifani)

Comment: The comment of @NicolasStifani concerns Windows, but I have a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll say it here instead: I'd simplify everything. So, save it as a csv file if you can and use the *readr* package. From there, you can call `read_csv`.

Perhaps even better, you could download the [preview release of RStudio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/) and, in the Environment tab, click *Import Dataset* before following the remaining instructions. Without knowing more, it is hard to tell if that will work, but I suspect that it should.

Comment: I had already downloaded RStudio. Indeed, when I clicked import Dataset, the table is displayed in RStudio, but It didn't change anything with the file `Classeur.1.xlsx` or `Classeur.csv`. Could you tell me what should be the difference in using the function `read.table()` ?