# Dealing with NA value in data importing loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm importing several hundred files into a single file in order to analyze is after using:

```
files.pet <- sort(list.files(pattern = '1998[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].pet'), decreasing = FALSE)
    all_data.pet <- NA;
    for (pet.atual in files.pet) {
      data.atual <-
        read.table(file = pet.atual,
                   header = FALSE,
                   sep = ",",
                   quote = "\"",            
                   comment.char = ";");
      data.atual <- cbind(data.atual, Desig = pet.atual)
      all_data.pet <- rbind(all_data.pet, data.atual)
    }
```

Which runs good until it finds one file giving this error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 399 did not have 9 elements
```

Which has a NA value in one of the columns, is there a way to tell the loop to ignore this and keep importing? Or should i just erase/replace NA in the row?

Also while I'm asking can anyone give me a insight on the meaning of:

```
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

I read around but had little luck understanding what it actually means.

Thanks alot! (sorry if the questions are pretty obvious but I'm new to R)

Comment: import data upto 398 and then in the second run, start from 400. You could use `skip` and `nrows` arguments in `read.table`

Comment: for skipping nulls, use `skipNul = TRUE`

Comment: also try `fill = NA` and see if it passes through line 399

Comment: I tried using it before, but it didn't work. Probably put it in the wrong place in the code but i'll see what i can find about it!

Comment: The fill = NA worked, gonna have a look on what it means! Any ideia about the other warning?

Comment: also change `fileEncoding` to a different encoding format and see if it passes through. I would first try `skipNul = TRUE`

Comment: This answer may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734911/warning-message-line-appears-to-contain-embedded-nulls

Comment: The values for fileEncoding may be UTF16LE or UCS-2LE

Comment: the skipNul does not solve the problem. As the for enconding tried both fileEncoding =  "UCS-2LE" and "UTF-16LE" and the warnings just went up xD

Comment: try `"UTF-16"` as value to fileencoding

Comment: Use `fread` from `data.table` package and select only columns  of interest.

Comment: @Sathish it's wierd, when i try and type of fileEncoding it only processes 183 observations (out of 2M)

Comment: @discipulus problem is that all columns are of interest, but thanks for the reply

Comment: see if you could import all data by reading them in chunks and also changing the fileconding. Later combine all together